# how to display uploaded files or images on template in django3

Tags: python, django, media, display

I only see the file path in the template. I can't see the file itself.
(django 3.x)

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

model.py

```
class EkleModel (models.Model):
    aKaydi = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='A KAYDI')
    bKaydi = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='B KAYDI')
    cKaydi = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='C KAYDI')
    upload = models.FileField(upload_to='media/%Y/%m/%d/', verbose_name='DOSYA YÜKLE')
    yuklemeTarihi =models.DateTimeField(default =timezone.now)
```

views.py

```
def index(request):
    girdiler = EkleModel.objects.filter(yuklemeTarihi__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('-yuklemeTarihi')
    return render(request, 'sayfalarUygulamasi/index.html', {'girdiler': girdiler})
```

index.html

```
<img class="card-img-top" src="girdi.upload">
<h4 class="card-title">{{girdi.aKaydi}}</h4>
<h4 class="card-title">{{girdi.bKaydi}}</h4>
<h4 class="card-title">{{girdi.cKaydi}}</h4>
<h4 class="card-title">{{girdi.yuklemeTarihi}}</h4>
```

Comment: DEBUG=true of false? girdi.upload -> girdi.upload.url https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/files/#using-files-in-models

Comment: you want to display the picture from the database?

Comment: Debug=True
image uploaded to media folder just not showing in template

Answer (score 0):

you have to loop through your queryset and .url to the image

```
{% for girdi in girdiler %}
  <img class="card-img-top" src="{{ girdi.upload.url }}">
  <h4 class="card-title">{{girdi.aKaydi}}</h4>
  <h4 class="card-title">{{girdi.bKaydi}}</h4>
  <h4 class="card-title">{{girdi.cKaydi}}</h4>
  <h4 class="card-title">{{girdi.yuklemeTarihi}}</h4>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
{% for girdi in girdiler %}
    <img class="card-img-top" src="{{me.upload.url}}">
{% endfor %}
```

and to your model

```
class EkleModel (models.Model):
    upload = models.FileField(upload_to='image/', null=True, blank=True,FileField)
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
urlpatterns = [
...
]+ static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns +=static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

and do migrations

Comment: I want to use filefield

Comment: I encounter this error before, and this pattern works on me

Answer (score 0):

`<img class="card-img-top" src="girdi.upload.url">` #add url after fieldname like this

Comment: Could you please show that I could not fully understand

Comment: inspect element image and look at src. you will see the path..then match with your database image path.. i hope you will get it

Comment: http://localhost:8000/media/media/2020/03/08/django.png - Page not found (404)

Comment: upload = models.FileField(upload_to='media/%Y/%m/%d/', verbose_name='DOSYA YÜKLE')
remove media from upload_to
exmp : upload_to = '%Y/%m/%d/'